# How to programmatically change OSx WiFi state using a script

Tags: macos, bash, networking, wifi

I am looking for a way to programmatically toggle the WiFi state of my laptop using a script. I am using MacOS (formally OSx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an alias in my `.zshrc`:

```
alias wifi:on="networksetup -setairportpower en2 on"
alias wifi:off="networksetup -setairportpower en2 off”
```

You need to change `en2` to the correct network adapter on your machine.

You can list all adapters using:
`networksetup -listallhardwareports`

You can also extract this logic to its own script or function that receives the `network-id` as a variable.

```
> ./toggle_wifi --id=2
```

**Update**

This question was also asked [apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194368/turn-wifi-off-on-with-a-single-key) and has a few well received answers. There is also a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/9140756) of a working version of the script.